# How to show json datasets in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have a scenario where I have to show json data in multiple divs. I am not sure how to do this. So far I was able to get the json data and print it in console.

Let's say I have six divs and each of them have the following fields:

```
        DIV 1
  ----------------
 | JName:    value1 |
 | JobSkill: value2 |
 | Descrip : value3 |
 | Salary:   value4 |
 | Experien: value5 |
  ----------------

        DIV 2
  ----------------
 | JName:    value1 |
 | JobSkill: value2 |
 | Descrip : value3 |
 | Salary:   value4 |
 | Experien: value5 |
  ----------------
```

I want to map each json dataset values to each div1, div2..etc

I have json like this:

```
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
```

so the first line or set of json should map to div1 and then the second one to div2 etc. How do I do this?

If I ng-repeat then it prints every thing in one div.

Html with six divs:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;" ng-controller="jobSummaryController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in token">
                {{ x.jobName }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">Some text </div>
    <div class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">Some text </div>
    <div class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">Some text </div>
    <div class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">Some text </div>
    <div class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">Some text </div>
</div>
```

angular controller:

```
myApp.controller('jobSummaryController', function ($scope, $http) {

    var url = 'rs/FetchJobSummary';
    $http.get(url).success(function (response)
    {
        $scope.token = response;

        console.log("job is:" + JSON.stringify(response));
    }).error(function (response)
    {
        console.log("error", response);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what directives are for https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put the `ng-repeat` on the div elements

http://plnkr.co/edit/TntCqHhbKDqaebDSlbOE?p=preview

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in token" style="border:2px solid black;">
      {{ x.jobName }}<br>
      {{ x.jobPrimarySkill }}<br>
      {{ x.jobRole }}<br>
      {{ x.jobDesignation }}<br>
      {{x.jobDescription}}<br>
  </div>
```

---

if you want to use a directive 
http://plnkr.co/edit/FWattoHd9yFmVbnCpUDC?p=preview

```
app.directive('mydir',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope : {  
      data : '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'mydir.html'
  };
});
```

and html call

```
  <div ng-repeat="data in token">

    <mydir data='data'></mydir>

  </div>
```

and the directive html :

```
<div style="border:2px solid black;margin:10px;">
  {{data.jobName         }}<br>
  {{data.jobPrimarySkill }}<br>
  {{data.jobRole         }}<br>
  {{data.jobDesignation  }}<br>
  {{data.jobDescription  }}<br>
  {{data.jobSalaryRange  }}<br>
  {{data.jobExp          }}<br>
  {{data.jobPositions    }}<br>
  {{data.jobPostedBy     }}<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I will plan on learning the directives. I am still new to angular. Thank you so much. But I didn't understand `"if you want to display a more elaborate "div" you should create a directive who display it and use it each time"`??

Comment: that is what a directive do. a directive have it's own controller, can have it's own scope or share her parent scope, and her own html. so each time you call it in the html ( `<yourDirName></yourDirName>` ) it display her html. so you can create a directive to display a user information ( your div1, div2...)

Comment: In your plunk, few of them are displaying keys instead of values? Could you check once please

Comment: Awesome Alainlb. A way for me to learn practically. Thanks for plunkers

Answer (score 3):

the element you use ng-repeat on will be repeated as many times as there's items in your array/object.
So the way you got about it if you want 6 divs is you use ng-repeat on the div element you want to be repeated:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in token" class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">
  <ul>
    <li ng-bind="x.jobName">
    </li>
    <li ng-bind="x.jobPrimarySkill">
    </li>
    <!--...-->
  <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<div ng-controller="jobSummaryController">
    <div class="job_box col-lg-offset-0" style="float: left; margin: 2px;"  
            ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        <ul>
            <li ng-bind="x.jobName"></li>
            <li ng-bind="x.jobxxx"></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its printing only the first value(Nasa scientist) in all the divs

Comment: <li ng-bind="x.jobName"></li>